# Store two chars without care of their order

Tags: mysql, rdbms

What is the most efficient space saving way to store two chars (0-255) if I don't care about their order? For example, pairs (33;44) and (44;33) contain the same numbers thus having 16 bytes (2 char fields) for storing them is redundant. Would it be still possible to search over the stored compacted values?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain your problem a little better.  And, keep in mind that AWS charges about $US 0.28 per gigabyle per year for high quality storage. Even if you save nine bytes per row (counting indexes) with this optimization, you''ll save a quarter of a dolllar per year. That's the cost of one kilowatt hour of electricity.

Comment: I'm unsure what can I add to the question. Two chars. Need to be stored in relational database. Storing it as two char fields is redundant due to combinations repetition. I don't care about electricity but I do care about requests processing speed (less data -> more speed).

Comment: "less data -> more speed" is not a truism. Redundancy can be faster or slower. Compressing & decompressing can increase or decrease speed. Speed depends on many things including patterns of usage & implementation of algorithms & storage. Always use a straightforward design. Relational DBMS generic querying for values suggests that the type of the values be the types of columns. Measure to demonstrate a problem & measure to verify a solution. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461 PS "Is it possible" is not a useful SO question.